# Plotly/R: create multiple rectangles

Tags: r, plotly, microbenchmark

I have two rather complicated plotly objects. For both I need to create rectangles for layouting and captions. I was kind of baffled to find that there is no function for this in `plotly` like there is e.g. in `ggplot2`.

I could think of two ways of how to create these rectangles:

1. Use lines and a [filled area](https://plot.ly/r/filled-area-plots/#interior-filling-for-area-chart)
2. Use the layout option and [draw rectangles](https://plot.ly/r/shapes/#rectangles)
3. Use the first solution and group with the `split`-argument

   ```
   library(plotly)

   ### 0. Create and order mock-data
   data_line=data.frame(x=rep(1:2,2),y=rep(1:2,each=2))
   data_fill=data.frame(x=rep(1:2,2),y=rep(0.5:1.5,each=2))
   mydata=data.frame(x=rep(1:2,4),y=rep(c(1:2,0.5:1.5),each=2),
                     id=rep(letters[1:2],each=4))
   mydata<-mydata[order(mydata$y,decreasing = TRUE),] # I tried if ordering helps

   ### 1. Solution using lines
   plines<-function(){
     p<-plot_ly() %>% 
       add_trace(data=data_line[data_line$y==2,],x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines',
                 split=~y,line=list(color='rgb(0,53,153)')) %>% 
       add_trace(data=data_fill[data_fill$y==1.5,],x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',
                 mode='lines',split=~y,line=list(color='rgb(0,53,153)'),
                 fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgb(0,53,152)') %>% 
       add_trace(data=data_line[data_line$y==1,],x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines',
                 split=~y,line=list(color='rgb(0,53,153)')) %>% 
       add_trace(data=data_fill[data_fill$y==0.5,],x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines',
                 split=~y,line=list(color='rgb(0,53,153)'),fill = 'tonexty',
                 fillcolor='rgb(0,53,152)')
     return(p)
   }

   ### 2. solution using layout options
   playout<-function(){
     p<-plot_ly() %>% 
       add_trace(data=data_line[data_line$y==2,],x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines',
                 split=~y,line=list(color='rgb(0,53,153)')) %>% 
       layout(shapes=list(list(type = "rect", fillcolor = 'rgb(0,53,153)',
                               line = list(color = 'rgb(0,53,153)'),
                               x0 = 1, x1 = 2, xref = "x",
                               y0 = 0.5, y1 = 1, yref = "y"),
                          list(type = "rect",fillcolor = 'rgb(0,53,153)',
                               line = list(color = 'rgb(0,53,153)'), 
                               x0 = 1, x1 = 2, xref = "x",
                               y0 = 1.5, y1 = 2, yref = "y")))
     return(p)
   }

   ### 3. Solution: Grouping with split does not work
   pwish<-function(){
     p<-plot_ly() %>% 
       add_trace(data=mydata[mydata$id=='a',],x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines',
                 split=~y,line=list(color='rgb(0,53,153)')) %>% 
       add_trace(data=mydata[mydata$id=='b',],x=~x,y=~y,type='scatter',mode='lines',
                 split=~y,line=list(color='rgb(0,53,153)'),fill = 'tonexty',
                 fillcolor='rgb(0,53,152)')
     return(p)
   }
   ```

To compare the solutions I used `microbenchmark`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(plines(),playout(),pwish(),times=1000L)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
 plines() 7.294808 7.924909 10.064783 9.187790 11.836938 21.23335  1000
playout() 6.345640 6.911258  8.818893 7.600264  9.845335 18.80933  1000
  pwish() 6.724504 7.316451  9.381053 7.990730 11.063591 25.15229  1000
```

Basically I have two questions regarding the interpretation of the benchmark:

1. Is there a fourth and faster solution than `playout()` I haven't thought of?
   Simple HTML or Javascript solutions are welcome as well.
2. Ignore the fact that `pwish()` doesn't work: Should `playout()` for longer data be the fastest?
3. Is a solution like `pwish()` even possible (Only relevant if your answer to 2. is 'no')

UPDATE: 
I have by now run `microbenchmark` again with bigger mock-dataset and while `playout` took about the same time, while the used time for `pwish()` increased a bit. Therefore I am quite sure now that `playout()` is the more efficient way to take.